# Not removing item from the cart

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart, cart

Below is my php code to show how I removing items from the cart. There is not error showing in webpage but also the item is not removing and cart is not updating. **Edited with full code**

```
    <div class="product_box">
            <form action="cart.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/data">

            <table align="center" width="700" bgcolor="skyblue">

                <tr>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                    <th>Product (s) </th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total Price</th>
                </tr>

        <?php  



        $total = 0;

         global $db;

         $ip = getIp();

         $sel_price ="select * from cart where ip_add='$ip'";

         $run_price = mysqli_query($db, $sel_price);

         while ($p_price=mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)) {

            $pro_id = $p_price['p_id'];

            $pro_price = "select * from products where product_id='$pro_id'";

            $run_pro_price = mysqli_query($db, $pro_price);

            while ($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro_price)) {

                $product_price = array($pp_price ['product_price']);

                $product_title = $pp_price['product_title'];

                $product_image = $pp_price['product_img1'];

                $single_price = $pp_price['product_price'];




                $values = array_sum($product_price);
                $total +=$values;

          //echo "Rs ." . $total;





            ?>

            <tr align="center">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]"></td>
                <td><?php echo $product_title; ?><br>
                    <img src="admin_area/product_images/<?php echo $product_image;?>" width="50px" height="50px">
                 </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="qty" size="3"></td>
                <td><?php echo "Rs." . $single_price ?></td>
            </tr>



            <?php   } } ?> 
            <tr align="right">
                <td colspan="3">
                    <b> Sub Total: </b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo "Rs." .$total; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="1"><input type="submit" name="update_cart" value="Update Cart"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue Shopping"></td>
                <td><button><a href="checkout.php">Checkout</a></button></td>
            </tr>


            </table>

            </form>

            <?php
$ip = getIp();

        if (isset($_POST['update_cart'])) {

            foreach ($_POST['remove'] as $remove_id) {

                $delete_product = "delete from cart where p_id=".$remove_id." AND ip_add=".$ip;
                $run_delete = mysqli_query($db, $delete_product);
                if ($run_delete) {
                    echo "<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";
                }

            }
        }

}


             ?>
        </div>
        </div>
```

I tried to check error by putting below code after if statement but not worked.

```
else { echo mysqli_error($db);}
```

Please help  Thanks.

Comment: did you check about `AND ip_add='$ip'` is matching or not ? I mean coming request and data stored in Db ?

Comment: yes.this is right.data is stroing in db

Comment: @SagarKodte plz do some debugging .add echo statements see where it brakes

Comment: Debug some informations
Check for value in $ip, $_POST . Maybe $_POST['remove'] is not an array?

Comment: actually i am new in php just started 2 days ago. i am using some tutorial in tutorial it's working but here not.

Comment: what is the value from your $ip variable. try doing writelog the mysql statements.

Comment: @mamosek i used name="remove[]" for checkbox which is used to select item

Comment: @RamansathiyaNarayanan how to do it? :(

Comment: let me help you, give a second.

Comment: ya  waiting. Thanks

Comment: @SagarKodte, trying using this, it will help you a lot, you can change the function name as you like and you can use it as I said in an example.

Comment: Incidentally, if it was me, I wouldn't delete the item, but instead hide it from view. That way the customer can easily undo this operation.

Comment: I am just following tutorial. Just started to learn php @Strawberry

Comment: **note:** IP addresses can be shared, thus there can only be one cart per IP address. This is a bad aproach

Comment: ya. got it. i already thought about it. i will learn it. Thanks @DarkBee

Comment: Be sure to show all [errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) when developing as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer i just added below value to input checkbox and it works.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $pro_id; ?> ">
```

Comment: As i said below ...
Why didnt you mark this answer as solved?

Comment: because you wrote wrong value that's why. i tried your answer but not worked. but i got my mistake from your answer. It helps me. so i upvoted your answer . thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try using writelog to check whether your mysql statements are getting values. Here is small function which will help you better in debugging.

```
<?php   
function writelog($content) {
    $file = 'log.txt';
    file_put_contents($file, date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." : ".$content."\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}

//Only display php errors to the developer...
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "put your localhost ip address")
{
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    $db_hostname = "localhost";
    $db_database = "ecommerce";
    $db_username = "root";
    $db_password = "";      
}
else
{
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    $db_hostname = "localhost";
    $db_database = "ecommerce";
    $db_username = "root";
    $db_password = "";              
}

//Establishing database connection
$db_connection = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database) or die(mysqli_error($db_connection));
```

Example how to use this function:
**write_log($delete_product)**;

This will create a text file where you have your current php file.
Learn a complete CRUD php mysqli example from this website:

[try this it will help you in understanding better](http://www.codingcage.com/2014/12/simple-php-crud-operations-with-mysql.html)

Comment: the file is not creating brother.

Comment: update your full code and it will be better for me to fix.And where have you defined the $db variable.

Comment: $db is my databade connect .it's in db.php

Comment: K, now where have you saved your files. If in a particular folder example: "C:\programFiles\SagarKodte\php", then here you will a text file named log.txt. Please have a look and I will be back in a minute

Comment: i saw. no file. i am using wamp server

Comment: Can you tell me what you have written in $db variable.

Comment: $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce"); this

Comment: check with my updated answer to how to make connection easily.Put that in a file named config.php and just declare it in your current page using include("config.php");

Comment: I have given you a link to learn better example. Its  a complete project of create, update, delete.

Comment: have a look at the link, it will help you better and if you find my answer useful upvote it.

Comment: yes. already did..and i got my error and just changed it works. I posted the answer here. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should in the line with checkbox

```
<tr align="center">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]"></td>
                <td><?php echo $product_title; ?><br>
                    <img src="admin_area/product_images/<?php echo $product_image;?>" width="50px" height="50px">
                 </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="qty" size="3"></td>
                <td><?php echo "Rs." . $single_price ?></td>
            </tr>
```

You should set a value = product_id in checkbox like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" id="<?=$pp_price['product_id']?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it will help you

```
$ip = getIp();
if (isset($_POST['update_cart'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['remove'] as $remove_id) {
        $delete_product = "delete from cart where p_id=".$remove_id." AND ip_add=".$ip;
        $run_delete = mysqli_query($db, $delete_product);
        if ($run_delete) {
            echo "<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";
        }
    }
}
```